# Combine two json into one in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have two Json strings and i want to combine it to one string.

I have tried this code but output it is showinw wrong output,

**Code:**

```
NSString* json1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* json2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

json1 = {"foo":"bar","bar":"foo","name":"craig"}
json2 = {"foo":"baz","bar":"fob","name":"george"}

NSArray *jsonArr = @[json1, json2];
NSLog(@"jsonArr %@",jsonArr);
```

**Output:**

```
(
    "{\n  \"foo\" : \"bar\",\n  \"bar\" : \"foo\",\n  \"name\" : \"craig\ \n}",
    "{\n  \"foo\" : \"baz\",\n  \"bar\" : \"fob\",\n  \"name\" : \"george\ \n}"
)
```

Where i am making mistake?
***Please help and thanks in adavance***

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Why don't you combine 2 string normally? `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", json1, json2]`

Comment: it should show valid combined json

Comment: it isn't valid json data, please check your json correct or not. "http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/"

Comment: I wish people would ask question like they want an answer.

Comment: Use `NSJSONSerialization` to get NSDictionary objects, then append them into a NSArray, and revert.

Comment: Start with compilable code that makes some sense to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly convert jason into String. Do the following if jsonData1 and jsonData2 are dictionaries, if not covert them to NSDictionary

```
NSString *jsonString=@"";
    NSString *key;
    for(key in [jsonData1 allKeys])
    {
        jsonString = [jsonString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@=%@,",key,[jsonData1 objectForKey:key]];
    }

    for(key in [jsonData2 allKeys])
    {
        jsonString = [jsonString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@=%@,",key,[jsonData2 objectForKey:key]];
    }
    jsonString = [jsonString substringToIndex:[jsonString length] - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two JSON strings representing two dictionaries

```
NSString *json1 = @"{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"bar\":\"foo\",\"name\":\"craig\"}";
NSString *json2 = @"{\"foo\":\"baz\",\"bar\":\"fob\",\"name\":\"george\"}";
```

To make a JSON array join the strings with comma separator and wrap it in brackets `[]`

```
NSString *resultJSONArrayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", [@[json1, json2] componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
// [{"foo":"bar","bar":"foo","name":"craig"},{"foo":"baz","bar":"fob","name":"george"}]
```